# JSON from Google Sheet to Android gives garbage

Tags: android, kotlin, google-apps-script, android-volley

I get a list of data from a google sheet into my android app. The Google Script runs properly and the test run also provides the correct output. However, the JSON data received in the android app looks like garbage. Here is my android side code. I am using Volley:

```
private fun getList() {
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/***********/edit#gid=0",
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            Log.d("MyMessage", response)
            parseItems(response)
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { responseEr -> }
    )
    val socketTimeOut = 500000
    val policy = DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)
    stringRequest.retryPolicy = policy
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}
```

The google appscript is as follows:

```
function doGet(e){

  var action = e.parameter.action;
  if(action == 'getList'){
    return getList(e);
  }
}

function getList(e){

  var records={};

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('*****');
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  data = [];

  for (var r = 1; r < 10; r++) {
     record = rows[r][1];
     data.push(record);
  }

  records.items = data;
  var result=JSON.stringify(records);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

 }
```

When I test the appCode script using the link provided I get the corect list as:

```
{"items":["****","****","****",........,"*****"]}
```

But the response log in the android app provides the following output:

< !DOCTYPE html>....< meta name="viewport" ................ .ritz .waffle a { color: inherit; }.ritz .waffle .s2{border-left: none;border-right: none;backgroun .......tom;white-space:nowrap;direction:ltr;padding"

What am I doing wrong over here

Comment: Provide details as written in the "usage guideline" of tag [tag:google-apps-script-web-application] like How is the web-app published?

Answer (score 1):

This returned:

["COL2",10,11,3,3,2,1,7,11,5,9,3,10]

From this sheet data:

```
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7,COL8,COL9,COL10,COL11,COL12
7,10,8,0,0,1,3,11,2,10,9,7
11,11,6,0,1,2,11,7,6,4,1,6
7,3,6,0,6,4,6,1,1,7,8,1
9,3,1,2,11,1,2,10,11,8,1,0
1,2,9,5,11,4,11,9,3,10,0,11
7,1,0,3,8,10,3,4,11,3,1,1
10,7,9,11,11,5,1,5,0,6,11,9
5,11,3,5,3,5,3,7,3,6,9,6
4,5,1,6,7,3,8,3,2,4,3,10
11,9,11,11,6,8,3,0,3,5,9,11
5,3,9,10,9,8,10,5,1,11,9,0
6,10,0,8,10,5,2,2,6,4,5,6
```

And this URL:

```
https://script.google.com/a/............/exec?action=getlist
```

and this gs code:

```
function doGet(e){
  if(e.parameter && e.parameter.action=='getlist') {
    return getList();
  }
}

function getList(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreasheet Id')
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet Name');
  var vA=sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().map(function(r,i){return r[0]});
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(vA));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android app has insufficient permissions to access the Apps script web-app and is redirected to Google's login page. Some solutions include:

- reduce web-app access permissions to "Anyone, even anonymous" OR
- increase android app's permission by registering with Google and oauth[<sup>1</sup>](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android)
- Alternatively, Use [google-sheets-api](/questions/tagged/google-sheets-api)[<sup>2</sup>](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#APIKey)